# Use promise in for loop for asynchronous data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am fetching match id and series id from my firebase database and storing it in object called ids and pushing ids values into an array called arr.

```
var options3 = {
  method: "GET",
  hostname: "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
  port: null,
  path: "/match.php?seriesid=SID&matchid=MID",
  headers: {
    "x-rapidapi-host": "dev132-cricket-live-scores-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "63e55e4f7fmsh8711fb1c0bd9ec2p1d8b4bjsne2b8db0a1a82"
  }
};
function makeStatusLive(data) {
  var arr = [];
  console.log("m aa gya", data[1]);
  let upcomingMatchRef = db
    .collection("Match_Creator")
    .doc("cricket")
    .collection("matchList");
  let queryUpcomingMatch = upcomingMatchRef
    .where("status", "==", "upcoming")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents.");
        return;
      }
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        // getting matchId and seriesId from the database and storing it in "ids" object
        let ids = {
          matchId: "",
          seriesId: ""
        };
        ids.matchId = doc.data().matchId;
        ids.seriesId = doc.data().seriesId;
        arr.push(ids);
        console.log(arr);
        // console.log(ids);
      });
    })
```

Now i am sending this ids values to 3rd party api to check status of the matches and return me the status values of respective match ids

```
    .then(() => {
      // passing "ids" value into options3 path to check for status of these particular matches from the api
      for (i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        var urlJson = options3.path;
        var matchid = arr[0].matchId;
        var seriesid = arr[0].seriesId;

        urlJson = urlJson.replace(/SID/g, seriesid); //replacing SID(in options3 path) with seriesId of "ids" object.
        urlJson = urlJson.replace(/MID/g, matchid); //replacing MID(in options3 path) with matchId of "ids" object.

        options3.path = urlJson; // final options3 path after passing "ids" values
        console.log(urlJson);

        var req = http.request(options3, res => {
          var chunks = [];
          var arr = [];

          res.on("data", chunk => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
          });
          console.log("aman", i);
          res.on("end", () => {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            var json = JSON.parse(body);

            const statusMatch = json.match.status;
            console.log(statusMatch);
          });
        });
        req.end();
      } //end of for loop
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
    });
}
```

Output what i am getting:

```
  functions: Beginning execution of "storeMatchData"
>  m aa gya COMPLETED
>  [ { matchId: '46202', seriesId: '2385' } ]
>  [ { matchId: '46202', seriesId: '2385' },
>    { matchId: '45879', seriesId: '2345' } ]
>  [ { matchId: '46202', seriesId: '2385' },
>    { matchId: '45879', seriesId: '2345' },
>    { matchId: '46117', seriesId: '2376' } ]
>  [ { matchId: '46202', seriesId: '2385' },
>    { matchId: '45879', seriesId: '2345' },
>    { matchId: '46117', seriesId: '2376' },
>    { matchId: '46290', seriesId: '2402' } ]
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  Error getting documents TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchId' of undefined
>      at upcomingMatchRef.where.get.then.then (C:\Users\AKASH\Desktop\predicta-function\functions\index.js:149:30)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>  aman 4
>  INPROGRESS
>  aman 4
>  INPROGRESS
>  aman 4
>  INPROGRESS
>  aman 4
>  INPROGRESS
```

its returning the status of first matchid only for every match id. I want status of each and every match id to be returned.

Comment: Better to use Promise.all for multiple requests

Comment: you're getting error "Cannot read property 'matchId' of undefined" because you rewrite `arr = []` right after receiving the first response

Comment: can you help me with the code please - @PoulUvarov

Comment: use dynamic Promise chaining, check my answer below. It will make a request and wait till its done and then goes to next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a dynamic Promise chaining:

```
.then(() => {
  var getStatusMatch = function(item, i) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var urlJson = options3.path;
      var matchid = item.matchId;
      var seriesid = item.seriesId;

      urlJson = urlJson.replace(/SID/g, seriesid); //replacing SID(in options3 path) with seriesId of "ids" object.
      urlJson = urlJson.replace(/MID/g, matchid); //replacing MID(in options3 path) with matchId of "ids" object.

      options3.path = urlJson; // final options3 path after passing "ids" values
      console.log(urlJson);

      var req = http.request(options3, res => {
        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", chunk => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        console.log("aman", i);
        res.on("end", () => {
          var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
          var json = JSON.parse(body);

          const statusMatch = json.match.status;
          console.log(statusMatch);
          resolve(statusMatch);
        });
      });
      req.end();
    });
  };

  function downloadChain(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((chain, item, index) => {
      return chain.then(() => getStatusMatch(item, index));
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }

  return downloadChain(arr);    
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("Error getting documents", err);
});
```

Comment: No its not working. what happening is first ids values is sending and returning its value which is "INPROGRESS" but what is happening is its not waiting for another ids value to be passed.

Comment: so what i need is first ids value it passed and check the value of status till then another ids values should wait until i get first ids value then second ids value should passed and check the value and so on

Comment: output: 
>  [ { matchId: '46202', seriesId: '2385' },
>    { matchId: '45879', seriesId: '2345' },
>    { matchId: '46117', seriesId: '2376' },
>    { matchId: '46290', seriesId: '2402' } ]
>  46202 in progress
>  45879 in progress
>  46117 in progress
>  46290 in progress
>  all done - @PoulUvarov

Comment: its not returning status for respective matchids

Comment: its throwing an error at downloadChain(arr) as Error: socket hang up
>      at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
>      at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)
>      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
>      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Comment: i've shown just idea, process request function should be yours, where you get response and parse your status

Comment: Will you please implement  your idea into my code and tell me the final code. i am not able to resolve it - @pauluvarov

Comment: in processrequest function how i will pass in var options3: path: "/match.php?seriesid=SID&matchid=MID", seriesid as SID and matchid as MID

Comment: output: i  functions: Beginning execution of "storeMatchData"
>  m aa gya COMPLETED
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  aman 0
>  INPROGRESS
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  aman 1
>  INPROGRESS
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  aman 2
>  INPROGRESS
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  aman 3
>  INPROGRESS

Comment: you can see the output. its taking same matchid and seriesid as a path - @pouluvarov

Comment: this path value in options3 variable is not updating i guess

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. actually i have to reset the path after resolving the promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use async - await solved your problem and use let in for loop

and use i insted of 0

```
var matchid = arr[i].matchId;
var seriesid = arr[i].seriesId;

.then(async () => {
  // passing "ids" value into options3 path to check for status of these particular matches from the api
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    var urlJson = options3.path;
    var matchid = arr[i].matchId;
    var seriesid = arr[i].seriesId;

    urlJson = urlJson.replace(/SID/g, seriesid); //replacing SID(in options3 path) with seriesId of "ids" object.
    urlJson = urlJson.replace(/MID/g, matchid); //replacing MID(in options3 path) with matchId of "ids" object.

    options3.path = urlJson; // final options3 path after passing "ids" values
    console.log(urlJson);

    var req = await http.request(options3, res => {
      var chunks = [];
      var arr = [];

      res.on("data", chunk => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      console.log("aman", i);
      res.on("end", () => {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        var json = JSON.parse(body);

        const statusMatch = json.match.status;
        console.log(statusMatch);
      });
    });
    req.end();
  } //end of for loop
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log("Error getting documents", err);
});
```

}

Comment: Still its not working. its taking first ids value and returning value for first ids for all remaining ids value.

Comment: >  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  /match.php?seriesid=2385&matchid=46202
>  aman 1
>  INPROGRESS
>  aman 2
>  INPROGRESS
>  aman 3
>  INPROGRESS
>  aman 0
>  INPROGRESS
>  INPROGRESS

Comment: its not working. see my output. its returning status of first matchid for every matchid values

Comment: its not waiting for second ids value to evaluate and return the value for it.